# What attack table do we use to resolve a thrown weapons attack?

Tags: attack, throwing-things, middle-earth-role-playing

I cannot find in the rules what table should be used to resolve attacks when done with a thrown weapon. For example, if a character throws an axe at an enemy, should AT-1 (1-handed slashing) or AT-4 (missile) be used?